# How can I add a min-width, non-wrapping element as an extra "column" inside a row using Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

#### Update: possible solution appended

I am creating a list using Bootstrap 3.  Inside each `LI` is a `<DIV class='row'>`, where a Bootstrap grid layout is used as normal.

**How can I need to insert a non-wrapping element at the beginning of each row?**

*For example, I want to insert a "grab handle" icon that can be dragged to re-order the items.*

I know that I can divide the columns up so that this "action" column gets a column of its own (e.g. `col-xs-1`).  However, especially on larger screens, this leaves an unsightly gap between the icon on the left, and the first column of data, or in the example below, the input box.

I've tried adding the element inside the first column, but then the two elements wrap as the available space decreases.

I'm open to any suggestions, so fire away.

Below is an example of what I am working with:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <ul class="">
    <li class="list-group-item active odd">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          Name
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          Description
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="row ">

        <!-- This is where I want to insert an element 
                to contain a  grab-handle or other action icon, 
                such as an edit icon -->

        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Red item">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="a red description...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
          <!-- removing the `form-control` class works better, 
                 but still wraps when the space gets too small -->
          <input type="text" value="Blue item">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="a blue description...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### UPDATE:  possible solution

I've got this apparently working by wrapping the `LI` contents in `white-space:nowrap` and using `display:inline-block` for the two divs (one for action button, and other for everything else in the row).

This seems to work, but I don't entirely understand why.

**Does anyone have any insight to offer on this?  And specifically whether this "solution" is invalid for any reason?**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">

  <ul class="">
    <li class="list-group-item active odd">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          Name
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          Description
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
          <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="display:inline-block; width: 100%; vertical-align:middle;">


          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group ">
            <input type="text " class="form-control " value="Red item ">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group ">
            <input type="text " class="form-control " value="a red description... ">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
          <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="display:inline-block; width: 100%; vertical-align:middle;">


          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group ">
            <input type="text " class="form-control " value="Blue item ">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group ">
            <input type="text " class="form-control " value="a blue description... ">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `clear:both;`?